# Uncaught SyntaxError:` Unexpected token import

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack, babeljs

I am working on a react application. Where I am using webpack and babel loader. 
In my react application I am using import statement many times which is working fine.

Now I have My another stand alone application which is working fine. 
Now  I am installing my standalone application in react application using npm. So I do

```
let standAloneApplication =  require("my_stand_alone_application")
```

But I get import error inside the standAloneApplication.  Where I have a line 
`import controller from "./controller" // Main.js:1Uncaught SyntaxError:` Unexpected token import

where as import statement in React application works fine.  also the stand alone application work fine at alone. but together It's giving SyntaxError

my webpack file

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'html');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'html');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/app.js',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
   devtool: "source-map",
   node: {
     fs: "empty"
   } ,
      module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.js?/,
        include : APP_DIR,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['babel?presets[]=react,presets[]=es2015,plugins[]=transform-decorators-legacy,plugins[]=transform-class-properties,plugins[]=transform-export-extensions'],
      },

      { test: /\.json$/, loader: "json" }
    ]
  }
}

module.exports = config;
```

main.js Code from stand alone application

```
import {Controller} from "./Controller/index.js"

export class Main () {

}
```

Comment: Could you try use a file .babelrc with the following content: 
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react"]
}, and I think that your path.resolve should not be 'htlm'

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `;` after `import {Controller} from "./Controller/index.js"` ? (just wondering)

Comment: If the es2015 is running correctly, ; is optional

Comment: @DavidR ;  is not mandatory.  @ Alessander França It works fine when i remove require of my stand alone application. I am using import many times else where.  .babelrc file is available at both place inside node module and react application root

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice the `exclude: /node_modules/` in your loader setup.

Since you installed your app/module using `npm`, it's located in that directory, and because of the exclusion it will not be transpiled by Babel.

Perhaps, but I'm not sure, you can add it explicitly to the `include` line:

```
include : [
  APP_DIR,
  path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/my_stand_alone_application')
]
```

Comment: Working like a charm

Comment: This works for me too, but the better solution will be to set up and run a build on my library (or Ashisha's stand-alone-app) which includes compiling the es6 with Babel. Then the 'dist' version will be ready to use as is, just like any other npm package.